# How to configure Firefox to open JPG files in an external application

Tags: firefox, jpeg

I often need to open JPG files from a website that are not rotated properly. I am using Firefox on Windows 10.

When I click on their link in Firefox, they open in a new tab and I have to rotate my screen to look at them upside up, because Firefox does not provide UI to rotate an image.

I can also right-click them and select "Save target as...", type in a file name (Apple users tend to name all files image.jpg) and then open the downloaded file.

What I want is that dialog popping up that lets me select an application to open the image in.

Is there a way to achieve that?

### Details

I set `pdfjs.disabled` to `true` in `about:config` so Firefox asks me what to do with PDF files. Is there a similar option for JPG files?

Comment: you will probably need to right click, save as and then open with whatever app you like to use, as I assume all site presenting any jpg would start to open in your external app (not even sure if you can change the behaviour for images)

Answer (score 0):

To send a displayed image (or link to an image) to an external viewer can be done
by either saving to a file or using an extension.

An extension that could help is
[External Application Button (WebExtension)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/external-application/):

> External Application Button allows you to define highly customizable toolbar button and context menu items for Firefox browser. Using this application for instance you can send current page to Chrome, Opera, or Internet explorer browsers. Or send selected text to a text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text. It is even possible to directly send image URLs to a photo editor of your choice or send download links to an external download manager like FlashGot extension in Firefox.

Comment: Well, that sounds reasonable and nice.
But alas, there are two options - one forwards the URL to my image viewer. That does not know what to do with it because it expects a local path. The other one prompts me where to save the downloaded file. That's what I wanted to avoid.
I know that I can configure Firefox to not ask me where to put downloaded files, but in all other cases (downloading EXE files for example) I want to be asked.

Comment: Another is [Image Assistant](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-assistant/).

Comment: I'm using that for now, although it has this annoying icon that pops up near images when the mouse pointer hovers over them and it does not support links, so you have to download the image twice. For some reason I cannot upvote your comment :( .

Comment: You need 15 reputation for upvoting, but can always mark an answer on your own post as accepted (the V sign).